# Can I integrate a native app in a web browser?

Tags: web, browser, progressive-web-apps

I need to display a native app (in my case, a video game built on unity) in a web browser page.

Local video and input streaming would be a solution, but video encoding is consuming too much computer resources.

Is there a way to display a native app in a web browser page?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you need to compile your application for WebAssembly. Or, to be more precise, cross-compile it, since WebAssembly binary code runs on a **virtual** stack machine.

You take your native code, compile it into a `.wasm` module, and then load that `.wasm` module with [WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/instantiateStreaming).

There are many toolchains that can have WebAssembly as the compilation target. I think the 2 most popular ones are [Emscripten](https://emscripten.org/) and [wasm-pack](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-pack).

There is also [wabt](https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt), but that is rather a set of lower level tools, not quite a toolchain.

And since you mentioned Unity, I have no experience with it, but there is [some official documentation on WebAssembly](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/Manual/webgl-gettingstarted.html).

[Here is a game](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/gynkq9/the_most_impressive_web_demo_ive_seen_unity_in/) that was developed in C# and cross-compiled to WebAssembly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't it just webgl with extra steps though?

Comment: I'm not sure how a Unity project gets compiled for the browser. My guess is that the render loop runs in WebGL (maybe WebGL 2), and the logic runs in WebAssembly. Here is another example of a little native game that was written in Rust and runs in the browser https://sandspiel.club/. Tip: open Chrome DevTools, go to the Network tab and refresh the page. You will see a `.wasm` module.